# Regex pattern for string manipulation

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following line:

```
{ "diameter":6 }   { 60 }  {"din":Anchor-1 R 6/5SPx3} {"length":30 } { Impact anchor } {"diameter":6 } { Online:0 } {, de03042 }
```

I'm trying to remove the following:

- whitespace between each opening and closing braces e.g. `{ "diameter":6 }   { 60 }` changes to  `{ "diameter":6 }{ 60 }`
- Any opened and closed brace that has a number inside it. In this case, `{ 60}` will disappear from the output.

I'm using the following pattern but it's not giving the desired output.

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"\s+[{}^]", ""); //Remove whitespace between each element

s = Regex.Replace(s, @"{{ [0-9^}]*}\}", ""); // Remove { 60 }
```

Desired output:

```
{ "diameter":6 }{"din":Anchor-1 R 6/5SPx3}{"length":30 }{ Impact anchor } {"diameter":6 }{ Online:0 }{, de03042 }
```

Current Output:

```
{ "diameter":660"din":Anchor-1 R 6/5SPx3}"length":30 Impact anchor HPS-1 R 6/5SPx3"diameter":6 Online:0 de03042
```

Could anyone please point out what's wrong with my patterns?

Comment: @Liam added the output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
(?<=})\s*(?={)|{\s*\d+\s*}
```

Replace with `string.Empty`.

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C%3D%7D)%5Cs*(%3F%3D%7B)%7C%7B%5Cs*%5Cd%2B%5Cs*%7D&i=%7B%20%22diameter%22%3A6%20%7D%20%20%20%7B%2060%20%7D%20%20%7B%22din%22%3AAnchor-1%20R%206%2F5SPx3%7D%20%7B%22length%22%3A30%20%7D%20%7B%20Impact%20anchor%20%7D%20%7B%22diameter%22%3A6%20%7D%20%7B%20Online%3A0%20%7D%20%7B%2C%20de03042%20%7D&r=)

Result:

[image]

**REGEX EXPLANATION**:

The pattern contains 2 alternatives (note the `|` alternation operator).

1. `(?<=})\s*(?={)`:

   - `(?<=})` - a positive lookbehind that makes sure there is a `}`
   - `\s*` - 0 or more (`*`) whitespace (`\s`)
   - `(?={)` - a positive lookahead that makes sure there is `{` right after the whitespace
2. `{\s*\d+\s*}`:

   - `{` - matches a `{` literally
   - `\s*` - 0 or more (`*`) whitespace (`\s`)
   - `\d+` - 1 or more digits
   - `\s*` - 0 or more (`*`) whitespace (`\s`)
   - `}` - matches a `}` literally.

Comment: Better than my answer!

Comment: @Liam, what was yours? I did not see :( MaskedAfrican: Actually, we can use alternation here with 1 regex since you replace with empty string. Otherwise, it would be more complicated, and would need code adjustment.

Comment: I deleted it, yours is much cleaner, I was using multiple patterns!